# how add coffeescript in svelte on Rails 7?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, svelte

I have a Rails 7 app with esbuild :

esbuild.config.js :

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const watch              = process.argv.includes("--watch");
const esbuild            = require('esbuild')
const coffeeScriptPlugin = require('esbuild-coffeescript');
const esbuildSvelte      = require('esbuild-svelte');
const sveltePreprocess   = require('svelte-preprocess');

esbuild
  .build({
    entryPoints: ["app/javascript/all.js"],
    bundle: true,
    outfile: "app/assets/builds/all.js",
    // outdir: "app/assets/builds/",
    plugins: [
      esbuildSvelte({
        preprocess: sveltePreprocess({coffeescript: { bare: true }}),
      }),
      // coffeeScriptPlugin({bare: true}), I TRIED THIS TOO...
    ],
    logLevel: "debug",
    watch: watch
  })
  .catch(() => process.exit(1));
```

my.svelte :

```
<script lang="coffee">
  test = ->
    console.log 'test coffee'

  test()
</script>
```

got an error :

> $ yarn build --watch yarn run v1.22.19 $ node ./esbuild.config.js
> --watch ✘ [ERROR] [plugin esbuild-svelte] Unexpected token
>
> ```
> app/javascript/all.js:3:3:
>   3 │ 1: 
>     ╵    ^
>
>  2: <script lang="coffee">
>  3:   test = ->
>          ^ 
>  4:     console.log 'test coffee' 
>  5:   test()
> ```
>
> The plugin "esbuild-svelte" was triggered by this import
>
> ```
> app/javascript/svelte_src.js:6:32:
>   6 │ import DemoSvelteComponent from './svelte/DemoSvelteComponent.svelte'
>     ╵                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```
>
> 1 error [watch] build finished, watching for changes... error Command
> failed with exit code 1. info Visit
> https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this
> command.

```
$ node -v
v18.4.0
```

package.json :

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "private": "true",
  "dependencies": {
    "@hotwired/stimulus": "^3.0.1",
    "@hotwired/turbo-rails": "^7.1.3",
    "esbuild": "^0.14.43",
    "esbuild-coffeescript": "^2.1.0",
    "esbuild-svelte": "^0.7.1",
    "sass": "^1.52.3",
    "svelte": "^3.48.0",
    "svelte-preprocess": "^4.10.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "node ./esbuild.config.js"
  }
}
```

**How add coffeescript in svelte with Rails ?**

Comment: maby it will help you: https://github.com/svelte-add/coffeescript

Comment: I see it, but it's works only with sveltKit and other. We don't have this tools when use esbuild with Rails...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't find the problem, I make new app and copy files, I don't see when exactly that works, but that works ... ^^

May be a bad invisible character was in file?

So It's works fine with include `esbuild-coffeescript` ...

That stay a mystery for my use case (I try checkout from git and bug don't come back.... realy strange)

Comment: These are not foolproof, but you can check for funky characters: `cat app/javascript/my.svelte | LESSCHARSET="ascii" less` or check all files `LC_ALL=c grep -Pn "[^[:ascii:]]" app/javascript/**/*.js`.

Answer (score 1):

This setup works with *node* `v18.4.0` `v16.15.1` `v14.19.3`. It turned out pretty much identical to what you have, except I don't know what's in your *all.js* file.

```js
// package.json

{
  "name": "app",
  "private": "true",
  "dependencies": {
    "@hotwired/stimulus": "^3.0.1",
    "@hotwired/turbo-rails": "^7.1.3",
    "esbuild": "^0.14.43",
    "esbuild-coffeescript": "^2.0.0",
    "esbuild-svelte": "^0.7.1",
    "svelte": "^3.48.0",
    "svelte-preprocess": "^4.10.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "node ./esbuild.config.js"
  }
}
```

```js
// esbuild.config.js

const watch = process.argv.includes("--watch");
const esbuild = require("esbuild");
const esbuildSvelte = require("esbuild-svelte");
const sveltePreprocess = require("svelte-preprocess");

esbuild
  .build({
    entryPoints: ["app/javascript/all.js"],
    outdir: "app/assets/builds/",
    bundle: true,
    sourcemap: true,
    plugins: [
      esbuildSvelte({
        preprocess: sveltePreprocess(),
      }),
    ],
    logLevel: "debug",
    watch: watch,
  })
  .catch(() => process.exit(1));
```

```
// app/javascript/all.js

import App from "./my.svelte";
new App({ target: document.body });
```

```html
<!-- app/javascript/my.svelte -->

<script lang="coffee">
  test = ->
    console.log 'test coffee'
  test()
</script>
```

Compiles:

```
$ yarn build --watch
yarn run v1.22.19
$ node ./esbuild.config.js --watch
[watch] build finished, watching for changes...
[watch] build started (change: "app/javascript/my.svelte")
[watch] build finished
```

and shows up in the browser console:

```txt
test coffee                                    my.svelte:1
```

---

This is a smaller working example, maybe it'll help eliminate the source of the error. It compiles *my.svelte* file directly and prints out the source.

```js
// package.json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "esbuild": "^0.14.43",
    "esbuild-coffeescript": "^2.1.0",
    "esbuild-svelte": "^0.7.1",
    "svelte": "^3.48.0",
    "svelte-preprocess": "^4.10.7"
  }
}

// esbuild.config.js
require("esbuild").build({
  entryPoints: ["app/javascript/my.svelte"],
  plugins: [require("esbuild-svelte")({ preprocess: require("svelte-preprocess")() })],
}).catch(() => process.exit(1));
```

```js
$ node --version
v18.4.0

$ node ./esbuild.config.js
import { SvelteComponent, init, safe_not_equal } from "svelte/internal";
function instance($$self) {
  var test;
  test = function() {
    return console.log("test coffee");
  };
  test();
  return [];
}
class My extends SvelteComponent {
  constructor(options) {
    super();
    init(this, options, instance, null, safe_not_equal, {});
  }
}
export default My;
```

Comment: `Unexpected token
    app/javascript/svelte_src.js:10:10:
      10 │  8: </script> -->
         ╵           ^
 9: <script lang="coffee">
10:   test = ->
              ^
11:     console.log 'test coffee'
12:   test()

  The plugin "esbuild-svelte" was triggered by this import
` I use node v17.7.1 I can try update...

Comment: I update node, nothing change... I edit my post and the error message... You keep `coffeescript` package but don't use it in build script... it's curious coffeescript works for you... I realy don't understand

Comment: @Matrix I'm not sure where `esbuild-coffeescript` is used, but it doesn't work without it. I can't even get the error that you're getting. It only failed for me on node v12 but with a different error. I tried on Ubuntu and OSX. You must have something else installed that's running with esbuild, like `esbuild-coffeescript` does. try removing *node_modules*. Try a smaller build. I see in your error `svelte_src.js` and `DemoSvelteComponent`, all these extra files are not needed while trying to debug.

Comment: it's same file, I just rename for abstract exemple, but nothing change ;) I will try on new app for see

Answer (score 0):

I've met the same problem in my rails app and my solution was using another build script

old:

```
"build-es": "esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets"
```

new:

```
"build": "node ./esbuild.config.js",
```